# How to convert FileInfo to FileInfo[] on string[]?

Tags: c#

I resolved my problem. But error when I was create constructor `LI` variable is `ListViewItem` but I can use this in `foreach` loop?.

```
ListViewItem LISTA = default(ListViewItem);
foreach (LISTA in this.lstImgAdded.SelectedItems) {
```

I'm trying to get Length of the list file with my code:

```
string[] filePaths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
List<FileInfo> fileInfos = new List<FileInfo>();  
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePaths);
    fileInfos.Add(f);
```

This show error like this:

> Cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'

Comment: you cannot convert a class to its exactly identical array of that class... just use: `FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);` for your foreach

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: It looks like you have a simple typo; just remove the `[]` from the type in the `f` variable's declaration. If that is not the problem, please improve the question so we understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Could try `FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);` instead?

Comment: The first part of the question and the second of the question seem like totally different questions... Perhaps you want to put up something else to link them?

Comment: It's getting more unclear with the edit!

Comment: @AlexJolig sadly... true... :(

Comment: The second of the question is different questions. I'm newbie and can't post more question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a `class` to its exactly identical array of that `class`. Just use: `FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);` for your `foreach` instead

Also, to get the "length of the list of file" will be identical to `filePaths.Length`

If you need the length, use `filePaths.Length` instead.

If you want to populate the `FileInfo`, do this instead:

```
string[] filePaths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
List<FileInfo> fileInfos = new List<FileInfo>();    
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePaths);
    fileInfos.Add(f);
    //long s1 = f.Length;
}
```

And all your file infos will be in the `fileInfos` and if you need the amount of item in the list, do it by `Count` like this: `fileInfos.Count`

Comment: Maybe you should figure out what the OP is actually asking, so your answer doesn't have to contain three different suggestions.

Comment: @PeterDuniho ok, I follow your suggestion and put up another comment.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: @dsfdsafd please read my comment in your question... we are trying to help actually

Comment: @lan can you help me to get the extension of a file?

Comment: @dsfdsafd extension? I think you can use `Path.GetExtension` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx in the filepath. Checkout the link

Answer (score 1):

Just change `filePaths` to `filePath` in the `foreach` loop

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
```

An alternative would be change the loop like this:

```
foreach (int s1 in filePaths.Select(filePath => new FileInfo(filePath)).Select(f => ((FileInfo[]) f).Length))
{
  //Do somthing with the s1 here
}
```